# CPU frequency control tool?

Tags: settings, power, cpu, performance

I am currently on Pop!_OS with Gnome. My preferred DE is Pantheon/Elementary OS. I need to toggle back and forth between CPU performance states based on my workload. Basically, whether I am doing audio work (recording or mixing) or writing/data entry.

Currently, I use https://github.com/martin31821/cpupower + indicator-cpufreq to gain access to most parameters I need to control

Does a tool exist for Elementary OS that can do any of

1. Save/recall profiles that contain different values for
2. Min/max target frequency
3. Enable/disable turbo boost
4. Change pstate governor between powersave and performance
5. enable/disable symmetric multithreading (many people ask why; each physical core only has one FPU, and thus disabling multithreading optimizes performance and more accurately reports CPU utilization in operations that rely heavily on FPU utilization)

Larger discussion on power control interfaces: https://pop-planet.info/forums/threads/power-management-design-interface.739

Answer (score 1):

Check this: https://snapcraft.io/auto-cpufreq Hope, this will suit your needs.

Comment: Thank you! I am checking it out. In particular I wonder whether it exposes the ability to set up situation-specific configurations, as there are scenarios where I do not want optimized for battery life, but I need reliable low latency, low throughout/quiet performance during multi-track recording, or low latency, high throughput (low battery life) performance during audio mixing with lots of DSP. I appreciate this tip, thank you!

Comment: ethan then you can install lowlatency kernel and choose it in GRUB after the installation and reboot.